# Почему в vs code обновления парные скобки не окрашиваются?

Tags: visual-studio-code

После обновления **vs code** перестал окрашивает парные скобки. До этого я использовал расширение **Bracket Pair Colorizer**. Но сейчас,обновленый vs code, не расширение не окрашивает парные скобки. Я пробовал разные способы, переустанавливал B**racket Pair Colorizer**, вручную настраивал в **setting.json**, но ничего не помогает.

```
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
"editor.guides.bracketPairs":"active"
```

Если кто-то также сталкивался с этой проблемой, пожалуйста, поделитесь, как вы ее решили.

Comment: Попробуйте эти настройки: `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true, "editor.bracketPairColorization.independentColorPoolPerBracketType": true, "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true, "editor.guides.bracketPairsHorizontal": true`

Comment: @OliverPatterson, К сожалению, это не помогло

Comment: Вы не на preview версии редактора?

Comment: Что за preview версия редактора? В первый раз слышу

Comment: Извиняюсь, insiders)